# ColorConverter fails with parsing ScRGB

Tags: c#, colors, string-conversion

I´m trying to parse a LinearGradientBrush from Xaml strings, without any problem I use the [`ColorConverter.ConvertFromString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter.convertfromstring.aspx) for normal text or html color conversion.

Recently I came across some colors parsed from Adobe Illustrator into Expression Blend using the ScRGB formatting ["sc#scA, scR, scG, scB"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms653055.aspx). That seems to break the ColorConverter, as the `ScA` value from the `Color` struct seems to parse the value wrong; for example 0.2 becomes 2 and 0.5 becomes 5.

My code is fairly straightforward:

```
string colorStr = "sc#0.117647059, 0, 0, 0";
Color color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString(colorStr);
Console.WriteLine(color.ScA);
```

Output: 1,176471E+08, Expected: 0,1176471

Is this a bug in the .NET Framework (I'm on 4)? Is there a workaround? Does anyone have a clean-fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a culture problem.  Clearly you are living in a part of the world where the decimal point in a floating point value is a comma instead of a period.  But your color string is formatted with a period.  So when the value is converted to float, it sees the period in the string as a thousands separator, not a decimal point.  And "0117647059" is indeed 1,176471e8.

You'll need to use the ColorConverter.ConvertFrom() overload, it accepts a CultureInfo reference.  Pass CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.  Or whack the Adobe tooling over the head somehow so it generates properly localized strings.

Comment: Hmm you are right! I find it kind of odd though, as the format I supplied is standard in XAML. Why won't the Static ColorConverter parse that correctly, I find that strange! I hate those Culture settings :(